# Implementing a scheduler that blocked until all the tasks are completed before taking in new tasks

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am quite new to using Java `SchedulerThreadPoolExecutor`. I would like to ask if there is a way to implement a scheduler that matches the scenario:

1. At time t, a scheduler will take in all the tasks that are not processed and processed them.
2. At time t+1, there are new tasks coming but the scheduler is unable to take them since all the tasks at time t have not processed finished. Even if some of the task at time t has finished processing, the scheduler is unable to take in new task from time t+1 until all the tasks have completely processed. If that is the case, the scheduler will block the task at time t+1. Till all the task t+1 have fully processed, then the scheduler will take in new tasks at t+1.

Comment: It is not entirely clearly clear what you say in point 2. I suggest you read it yourself again, see why its weird, and rephrase yourself.

Comment: Also, you use terms like `t` and `t+1`. It sounds to me like you're looking at time as relatively large, but discrete chunks (like clock ticks). What does the `1` in `t+1` signify to you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to define task processing periods, where no task will cross a period boundary. Two questions/hints:

- Why do you need to use [`SchedulerThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)? Unless you intend to use its timer-like capabilities, which would probably conflict with your task period requirement anyway, a simple [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) should be enough.
- Have you considered restructuring your code to use [`invokeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)?

Comment: I have the intention to use the timer-like capability. I am thinking like if I will to start the scheduler at a specific time say 3 am, then for every interval, it will start to run task like say 1 minute. I am not sure if it is doable in this way. I intend to use config file such that I can configure the time as well as the interval to run the scheduler.

I have not consider using invokeAll. How does it help?

Comment: @ktlim: `invokeAll()` will launch all supplied tasks and then wait until they are complete. It allows a level of determinism by blocking the submitter thread until all tasks are finished...

Comment: @ktlim: It seems to me, however, that what you need is more complex than a simple job scheduler. It might be best if you described your actual problem, rather than what you want your scheduler class to do. For example, what happens if the next interval arrives and some tasks have not been completed yet?

Comment: I find that if I will to describe the problem, it will be difficult. I look at the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor api documentation, there seem to be no way I can block the scheduler from running if there are new tasks that are coming in at time t+1 if the tasks at time t have not been processed. Basically, I just wonder if there is a code or way that can achieve the purpose of blocking the scheduler till the scheduler has finished all the tasks from time t.